# unnecessary "['', '']" when parse CSV files using python csv module

Tags: python, csv

everyone.

I want to parse a csv `"20568078","240431","jpg","St, Carolina 1920",,`into `["20568078","240431","jpg","St, Carolina 1920","",""]`

by using this:

```
string=r'"20568078","240431","jpg","St, Carolina 1920",,'
reader = csv.reader(string)
for r in reader:
    print (r)
```

I got the output:

```
['20568078']
['', '']
['240431']
['', '']
['jpg']
['', '']
['St, Carolina 1920']
['', '']
['', '']
```

I want to konw how to delete the unnecessary `['', '']`, and change the last two `,,` to `""` and `""`

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `StringIO` to treat this stings as file-like object

```
>>> import csv
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> string=r'"20568078","240431","jpg","St, Carolina 1920",,'
>>> for r in csv.reader(StringIO(string)):
        print (r)


['20568078', '240431', 'jpg', 'St, Carolina 1920', '', '']
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader

> `csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel', **fmtparams)`
>
> Return a reader object which will iterate over lines in the given `csvfile`. `csvfile` can be any object which supports the iterator protocol and returns a string each time its `next()` method is called — `file` objects and `list` objects are both suitable.

The problem with your code is that you are passing a single string to the `reader`. The reader then interprets **each character** as a **line**. eg.

```
>>> string=r'"20568078","240431","jpg","St, Carolina 1920",,'
>>> i = iter(string)
>>> next(i)
'"'
>>> next(i)
'2'
```

is approximately how `csv` calls `next` on the iterable you pass to it. However you use doublequotes which represent multiline strings which explains why they all come in one piece.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a list of strings to `csv.reader` constructor:

```
>>> import csv
>>> string=r'"20568078","240431","jpg","St, Carolina 1920",,'
>>> reader = csv.reader([string])
>>> print reader.next()
['20568078', '240431', 'jpg', 'St, Carolina 1920', '', '']
```

Comment: Newlines inside quoted strings are OK though.

Comment: correct, it really depends on OP's needs, if OP only ever has a single row, this is the better answer